# How to run export DISPLAY with PHP for Selenium?

Tags: php, python, selenium, ubuntu

I've tried to this :

```
shell_exec('export DISPLAY=:99 & python3 index.py');
```

and getting following error :

> Connecting to Marionette on localhost:40018 Error: GDK_BACKEND does
>   not match available displays`

From `geckodriver.log`

But, if I run this from SSH `export DISPLAY=:99 & python3 index.py` than all work fine.

Comment: Usually your first monitor is `DISPLAY=":0.0"`. Maybe you can try that? ..so you're trying to execute a python script from a php script which executes java?

Comment: @MichaelD. I try to run python (selenium) script on VPN, without any monitor.